# Property or indexer cannot be assigned to - it is read only.C#

Tags: c#

i want to write a program to capitalize the first letter of each word of a given string By C#.
it give me an error:Property or indexer cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.
and when i used ToUpper the error is: "ToUpper Does not exist in current context".

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Csharp_Training
{
    class Program
    {
        static string Captilaize(string Text)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Text[i] = ToUpper(Text[i]);//here when i used Text[i] giv me error: Property or indexer cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
                    
                }
                else if (Text[i - 1] == ' ')
                {
                    Text[i] = ToUpper(Text[i]);// ToUpper Does not exist in current context
                }
            }
            return Text;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write(Captilaize("cpp string exercises"));
        }                           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To address the immediate problem, the indexer to a string is *readonly*

[String.Chars[Int32] Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.chars?view=net-5.0)

> Gets the Char object at a specified position in the current String
> object.

The reason why, is because string are *immutable* (for a whole bunch of reasons), Not to mention they can be interned. Being able to mutate a string like this would require a new allocation anyway.

You will either have to rebuild the string or work with a char array to achieve what you want.

Your second issue, is you will need to identify what constitutes a word by either splitting the string, or using regex, then applying the upper case to the first character of each word.

However, What you are describing is called *Title Case*. There has been a method to do this in C# since *.Net 1.1* in the Globalization namespace.

[TextInfo.ToTitleCase(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=net-5.0)

> Converts the specified string to title case (except for words that are
> entirely in uppercase, which are considered to be acronyms).

**Example**

```
string myString = "Some random string to prove this example";
var myTI = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo

// or 
// var myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo;

Console.WriteLine( myTI.ToTitleCase( myString ) );
```

**Output**

```
Some Random String To Prove This Example
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dQavzf)

Answer (score -1):

[ToUpper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=net-5.0) is a method you call on a string that returns a string with all letters capitalized.
You want to index the first character in the string and call the method on only this.

Comment: Well, you'd really want to call `Char.ToUpper()` as each character in a string is a `char`

Comment: Depends on how you implement it, you could use either method.  But based on OP's implementation, you're right.

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking for, anyway - _i want to write a program to capitalize the first letter **of each word** of a given string_

Comment: good point, after a more careful re-read of OP's post, I agree.